# How would I return up to a higher up line and have it execute in Python?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to programming and am trying to create a very simplistic dungeon game.  I have most it working but I'm having a slight issue. Here is my code:

```
print("Welcome to Matt's Dungeon!")

user = ""
stop = "q"

while user != "q":
first = input("You are in the kitchen. There are doors to the south (s) and east (e). ")
if first == "s":
    print("You entered the furnace and fry yourself to death!")
    break
elif first == "q":
    break
elif first == "e":
    second = input("You are in the hallway. There are doors to the west (w), south (s), and east (e). ")
    if second == "w":
        first == "s"
    elif second == "q":
        break
    elif second == "e":
        print("You are in the library. You found the princess! You are a hero!")
        break
    elif second == "s":
        third = input("You are in the living room. There are doors to the west (w) and north (n). ")
        if third == "w":
            print("You entered the furnace and fry yourself to death!")
            break
        elif third == "n":
            first == "e"
        elif third == "q":
            break


print("Goodbye!")
```

The issue that I'm having is that if the user enters "n" in the living room I want it to go back to the hallway but the program always sends it back to the original kitchen.  However, if the user enters "w" in the hallway this works fine and returns it to the previous room, the kitchen.  Any ideas on how I might be able to fix this? Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets ignore the indentation problems which presumably you copied incorrectly.

Your control flow is a huge mess.  Basically lets look at your basic structure:

```
while True:
  first = input("You are in kitchen")     
  # additional program logic
```

Can you see why, whatever happens with the remaining logic you do here you will always return to the kitchen after a `continue`?

One option to get the structure that you actually want is to program a little less sequentially.  Here is a psuedocode example of one possible way to design your game, with some parts of the design left intentionally unspecified.  I provide this to get you to think about ways in which you might design the game in a way that makes sense.

```
class Room():
  def __init__(self,north,south,east,west):
    self.north=north
    self.south=south
    self.east=east
    self.west=west

kitchen = Rooms(None, 'hallway', 'library', None)
#initialization of other rooms are left as excercise to the reader

current_room = kitchen

while True:
  print "You are in the %s" % current_room
  move=raw_input("Where do you want to go")
  if move=='q':
    print "bye"
  if move=='e':
    current_room = current_room.east

  #much logic is left as an exercise to the reader
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) comprised of a key which represents a room and a value of a list of place you can go.

For example:

```
# these match up to indexes for the list in the dict directions
NORTH = 0
EAST = 1
WEST = 2
SOUTH = 3

directions = {
    "living room": ["dining room", None, None, "bedroom"]
}

# the current room, represented by the keys you create
current_room = "living room"
# an example imput
direction = "n"

if direction == "n":
    possible_room = directions[current_room][NORTH]
    if possible_room:
        current_room = possible_room
```

Some very sloppy example code but it gets my point across. The general idea of coming up with a program is looking into how you can store your data such as using dictionaries in Python.

Python has plenty of data types that are worth looking into.

I will leave you to fix the code now since you have gained a new perspective into solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is messed up.

Put `first = input("You are in the kitchen. There are doors to the south (s) and east (e). ")` before the while loop.